# Spring Data Mongo: Find by array intersection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I use Spring Data DSL to query MongoDB in the following way:

```
Page<Member> findByCommunitiesCodeContaining(String code, Pageable pageable);
```

It returns all Members of a community with a given code.

**Problem:** I need to pass a collection of community codes and return Members that participate in at least one community from the listed codes (where intersection of communities is not empty).

I browsed the Spring Data Mongo documentation but couldn't find a DSL supporting this case.

**Question:** How do I query records with intersection of collections?

**More details.** Here is how my structure looks on Java side.

```
@Document
public class Member {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Community> communities;
}
```

Community:

```
public class Community {
    private String region;
    private String code;
}
```

Comment: Try `Page<Member> findByCommunitiesCodeIn(Collection<String> code, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: @Valijon thank you. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, better answer is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/30123996/3710490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30123996/3710490)

Comment: @Valijon, if I had found that answer I wouldn't have created this question. I would still suggest you to post an answer as there is a big chance that I am not alone.

Answer (score -1):

One option might be to use a regex

```
Page<Member> findByCommunitiesCodeRegex(String code, Pageable pageable);
```

The code should be a regex like:

```
String code = (code1|code2|code3|....)
```

Hope it helps, I haven't tried it but it is worth trying.